# How can I include default model as reference name in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, node-modules

I have a module students which I export as a default module

```
export default students
```

I need to import this with reference name

I tried: `import students as studentModel from "../students";`

But it's give me error like studentModel is not definded,

if i user `import students from "../students";`

then student is work, anyone can guide me what I missed.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can name the variable, that you're storing the module in, anything you like.

```js
import studentModel from "../students";
// this is just fine

import students from "../students";
// so is this

import dogsGoToHeaven from "../students";
// and this
```

Comment: @RahulBhobe he's attempting to name the default import.

Comment: That is correct. Could you edit your answer to indicate why `import students as studentModel` does not work?

Comment: @RahulBhobe its a syntactical error. There's not much to say about it.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

```
export students;
import {students as studentModel} from "../students";
```

[Exported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) object will contain property `students` and when [imported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) it is renamed as `studentModel`.

### Option 2

```
export default {students};
import {students as studentModel} from "../students";
```

[Exported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) object will contain property `students` and when [imported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) it is renamed as `studentModel`.

### Option 3

```
export default students;
import studentModel from "../students";
```

Since `students` itself is [exported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) as `default` the exported object itself is `students`. You could directly rename the [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) to anything you desire.

Comment: `import students as studentModel from` is a syntactical error. There's nothing in the `import` spec that says you can use `as` in this manner.